# How to use OpenGrok with GitHub?

Tags: github, opengrok

GitHub's advanced search is okay, but the OpenGrok has some desirable features.

To use OpenGrok with GitHub hosted repo's will I have to:

1. Set up my own OpenGrok server
2. Clone the various repos
3. Schedule pulls to keep up-to-date

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the general idea, but:

2/ should be a full clone:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/user/repo
```

3/ can be triggered [**by a webhook**](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/): if you listen for the [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) they generate, you can then pull only where there is a push on the GitHub repo, and push back to your OpenGrok server.

Note: you might want to [exclude pull refs](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-mirror-a-github-repository-without-pull-refs.html) (`refs/pull/{id}`), that is the **[pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)** that GitHub stores in its Git repo.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new service you can try

[www.insight.io](http://www.insight.io)

it provides IDE-like code intelligence and allows you to import directly from github. Also it's web-based so you can practically visit it from anywhere.

Comment: insight io was purchased by Elastic.  The service appears to be gone now.

Comment: the link is down, looks like it's down for 3 years (see comment above)